# What parameter do i use in pd.read_sql_query() to update the column list instead of "column" in pd.read_parquet(columns = list())

Tags: python, pandas, list, rdbms, parquet

According to pandas documentation -

> columnslist, default=None If not None, only these columns will be read
>   from the file.

Eg - pd.read_parquet(columns = list(abc))

Similarly i want a replacement of the ***"columns"*** attribute while reading from pd.read_sql_query()

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Instead of using pd.read_sql_query()

You can use -

```
self.df = pd.read_sql(columns=list(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
cols=["a","b"]
sql = "SELECT '{}' FROM mytable".format("','".join(cols))
```